# Laravel Middleware Redirect If Table is Empty

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, migration, middleware

I am trying to set up middleware that prevents a user from visiting a URL unless they have saved their shipping address information to my database. However, it is not working.

Migration:

```
Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('street');
            $table->string('city');
            $table->string('state');
            $table->string('zip');
            $table->string('country');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->user()->addresses('id')) {
            return redirect('shipping');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addresses()` relationship method returns a `QueryBuilder` which is `true`thful.
I recommend that you check for the count of *addresses* instead by using the [aggregate method](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#aggregates) `count`.

```php
if ($request()->user()->addresses()->count() == 0) {
    return redirect('shipping');
}
```

Comment: Small tip: the query builder also provides the `exists()` and `doesntExist()` methods to check for existence/absence of related records, this would result in an EXISTS query instead of a COUNT one at a database level in more semantical way

Comment: I tried this method before I posted this question, but I was doing "if (auth()->user()->addresses()->count() == 0)", which was giving me an error. Your method works. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

if your middleware name is relation for ex then you can give a param(name of relationship) then use it in your middleware like this
web.php

```
Route::get('shipings/{user}', 'GetShipingController@index')->middleware('relation:addresses');
```

and middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $relation)
{
    if (!$request->user()->{$relation}()->count()) {
        return redirect('shipping');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```